# Can we take a logarithm of an infinite product?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have an infinite product $S = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ of positive real numbers. Then is it always the case that
$$
\log(S) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n ?
$$

I am sure this is the case, but I wanted to make sure. 
Thank you!

Comment: If the infinite product converges to a positive number, then continuity of the logarithm function permits the interchange of the limit and log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n&=\log\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^ka_n\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\log\prod_{n=1}^ka_n\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\log a_n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log a_n
\end{align}
I was able to switch the $\log$ and the $\lim$ because $\log$ is continuous.

Comment: It's may seem like splitting hairs, but writing $\ln \prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ when $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$ itches a bit. :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, there. But if you continuously extend $\log$ to be a function from $[0,\infty]$ to $\overline{\Bbb R}$ (the extended reals) then it all works out. (I'm assuming that all of the $a_n$ are positive so that all of the summands of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log a_n$ are defined.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes (with a small caveat on whether you want to deal with $-\infty$ as a sum). If the product converges to some $S > 0$, then
$$\ln \prod_{n=1}^N a_n\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \ln S$$
by continuity of the logarithm. But we do have
$$
\ln \prod_{n=1}^N a_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \ln a_n
$$
so we do have that the series $\sum_{n=1}^N \ln a_n$ is convergent, and its limit is indeed $\ln S$.

Now, if $S=0$, you do have $\sum_{n=1}^N \ln a_n \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} -\infty$, but it's up to you whether you want to call this "$\ln S$"...