# When is the limit of an infinite product equal to the infinite product of the limit?

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

For a finite case we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\cdot g(n) =\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\cdot\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)$ however when is it possible to interchange the folowwing?

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n f(i)$

A specific problem I have is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2i-1}{3i-2}$. I tried taking the natural logarithm and this results in $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{2i-1}{3i-2}\right)$.

If I pass the limit then Ill be multiplying 2/3 infinitely often resulting in zero. Is this logic sound? Come to think of it, $\frac{2n-1}{3n-2}<1$ for every $n>1$ so the product is zero. No need to pass the limit. However the original question with $f(n)$ is still interesting.

Comment: Take the log, and this becomes a question about infinite sums

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : only on commutative fields.. ? joking, but if $f(n)$ were  matrices, I wouldn't be sure of the answer

Comment: For a fixed n, the sum interns of log approaches -infinity.... So taking exponentials we approach to zero. As you vary n this is unchanged. So the limit should be zero. I am not sure where you used commutativity here.

Comment: I suppose that for $n$ large enough, your individual fraction factors are less than $3/4$, so that your product is dominated by $\lim_n(3/4)^n$, going to zero. Not necessary to bother with logarithms.

Comment: Regarding this: "$\frac{2n-1}{3n-2}<1$ for every $n>1$ so the product is zero." This is **false**. It'll be true if you replace $<1$ by $<.99$, for example, but with $1$ the general statement is false.

Comment: However, this expression is meaningless: $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$ The inner part means $f(1)f(2)f(3)\dots$, so what does it mean to let $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637912/can-we-take-a-logarithm-of-an-infinite-product (@ThomasAndrews: I assume the OP meant $\prod_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty }\prod_{n=1}^N f(n)$ and mixed the two notations.)

Comment: But that's a very different type of limit. I suspect the OP mean something like $\lim_{m\to \infty} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} f_m(n)$, but it is unclear. @ClementC. There is no interchange going on in OPs limit, either way, I guess.

Comment: Well, in his/her example, we do have the single function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{2x-1}{3x-2}$, and the infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty f(n) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{3n-2}.$$
The "interchange" asked about appears to be more related to taking the logarithm, from the rest of the question, and swapping $\ln$ and $\sum$. There indeed is a fair bit of confusion in the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the limit is edited. Since the limit depends on $n$ I don't think we can change the order of operations.