# Can the Infinite Product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$ Converge or Diverge to Zero?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, infinite-product, conjectures

Can the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$ converge or diverge to zero when the sequence $a_n$ is monotonically increasing? I conjecture that this is impossible given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ by the monotonic increase of the $a_n$. However, I don't know of a rigorous proof or disproof of this, and analyzing convergence of infinite series and infinite products is not something I am very familiar with. If someone could provide a proof or disproof of this conjecture (preferably with a reference to a known theorem), or explain what additional restrictions need to be imposed on $a_n$ for the conjecture to hold, I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Problems about the "divergence to zero" of an infinite product are often successfully attacked by taking the logarithm to obtain an infinite sum (series).  See [this earlier Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637912/can-we-take-a-logarithm-of-an-infinite-product) on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q_n=\dfrac{1}{1+a_n}$ be such that $0\lt q_n\lt 1,$ then by the elementary theory of [infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria) $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q_n)$ converges to a non-zero number if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_n$ converges.
This clearly gives you a criteria to find the convergence to a non-zero number.

For example: if you set $a_n$ to be the $n$th prime (as mentioned in your comment), then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_n$ diverges and therefore ....

Comment: There are a few things that I am confused about here. First, your source seems to indicate that we would need $\prod_{n=1}^\infty log \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$ rather than $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q_n)$. Also, Diego Zhang and @achille hui indicate that the product converges, while your criterion indicates it diverges. Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: @MathRules: If you read the Wikipedia page carefully, you will see the criteria for convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q_n).$ Also what achille hui proved is the product "diverge to zero." Therefore does not contradict with what I have wrote in my answer.

Comment: You are correct. I thought you were referring to formulas at the top of the page, my mistake! The criteria for $\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1-q_n$ is indeed there, I just had missed it.

Comment: @MathRules: I'm glad, if I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Every term is less than $1$, so it converges to a constant less than 1.

Take $a_n=n$, and the product converge to $0$.

Take $a_n=2^n$, and the product converges, but not to $0$. This can be obtained by taking the logarithm and using the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x$.

Comment: What happens if $a_n$ is the $n$th prime? Could we take the logarithm and then apply the Prime Number Theorem (or some other theorem) to show the product converges to a nonzero value?

Comment: @MathRules If $a_n$ is $n^{th}$ prime, the limit is $0$. Loosely speaking, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_n}{p_n+1} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+ p_n^{-1}} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1 - p_n^{-1}}{1 - p_n^{-2}} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(1)} = 0$